# fatal error: Uncaught EasyPost woo trade in

Tags: php, wordpress, easypost

Fatal error: Uncaught EasyPost\Error: Unable to complete shipment purchase. Please contact support@easypost.com. in /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/EasyPost/lib/EasyPost/Requestor.php:268 Stack trace: #0 /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/EasyPost/lib/EasyPost/Requestor.php(252): EasyPost\Requestor->handleApiError(‘{“error”:{“code…’, 422, Array) #1 /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/EasyPost/lib/EasyPost/Requestor.php(123): EasyPost\Requestor->*interpretResponse(‘{“error”:{“code…’, 422) #2 /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/EasyPost/lib/EasyPost/Shipment.php(116): EasyPost\Requestor->request(‘post’, ‘/shipments/shp*…’, Array) #3 /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/label.php(46): EasyPost\Shipment->buy(Array) #4 /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/woo in /home/adminofferzone/offerzoneusa.com/wp-content/plugins/woo-ship-labels-master/EasyPost/lib/EasyPost/Requestor.php on line 268

how i fix this i have added trade in plugin and shipping label generator plugin
setup all things in easypost

Answer (score 1):

In the event of a client or server error, the response will contain the standard 4xx or 5xx respectively, accompanied by a well-formed JSON body describing the issue (e.g., a required field was omitted, a purchase failed, etc.)

Each client library will encapsulate these errors and raise an exception, in addition to other exceptional cases, such as network failures. It is recommended to handle exceptions gracefully and to report any issues to support@easypost.com.